# Valid USA Visa Barcode Corner Cut

Tags: visas

I'm Chinese. I have a 10years USA Visa in my old passport. During old passport renewal due to no page left, the USA Visa Page was cut -- at barcode corner. Does this affect my next entry and do I need to apply for new Visa page?

Comment: I am pretty sure it does.

Answer (score 3):

You can not travel to the USA using an old visa that is damaged or mutilated in any way.

I am not sure if the US Embassy in China will treat this as simply a renewal / replacement or if they will make you apply for a totally new Visa, as they do in a number of other countries.

Comment: I did not do anything wrong -- my USA Visa was pasted on "Observation" Page wrongly and right at the back of my old passport barcode control page which has to be cut as cancellation when issuing a new passport from CHN embassy. I hope USA Embassy can assist for New Visa REPLACEMENT

Comment: All you can do is ask, if they made a mistake mounting the visa, they may simply replace it.  Or they may go by the rules.